# LU decomposition and four fundamental subspaces relation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Is there a any relation between four fundamental subspaces of A and LU for matrix A = L U ?

Comment: I take it the "four fundamental subspaces" of a matrix are the row space, the column space, the left nullspace, and the right nullspace, right?

Comment: row sspace , col space , null space and left null space. exactly.